# Referência ao usuário (@) é removida pelo sistema

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, comentários, notificações

Agora, várias vezes que eu vou usar o @ em comentários, toda o nome (por exemplo: @LucasHenrique) desaparece. O que está acontecendo?

Comment: poderia explicar quais sao os passos para reproduzir o erro?

Comment: Entendi o que está acontecendo, qualquer referência a um usuario usando o @ está simplesmente desaparecendo apos clicar em Adicionar comentários. Muito estranho mesmo.

Comment: Quando a notificação já ocorre por outro motivo, ela é removida se inserida manualmente. Por exemplo, eu não preciso notificar o Lucas Henrique com @, porque estou comentando na pergunta dele e ele será notificado de qualquer maneira. Quanto a você, @Math, não tenho certeza, por isso inclui o @ no seu username.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu fui notificado agora. Acho que eu não consegui notificar agora a pouco pq eu tentei te notificar mas vc era o autor da respsota, aquela dos enlatados.

Comment: Então, naquele caso eu recebo notificação sempre, então o sistema remove o @nome porque é desnecessário.

Comment: @Math recebeu notificação do comentário acima? Não incluí seu nome para testar.

Comment: Não, só na última. Acho que está solucionado o problema.

Comment: Ah, e algumas vezes o nome dos usuários ativos não aparece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problema temporário (antigo!). Resolvido.